# Close old instance of application

Tags: c#

I'm developing a program, of which only one instance can run. I know I can apply mutex to prevent multiple instances from running.

But I want it so if a new instance of an application runs, it should terminate the old one. 
The executable will always have the same name.

I've tried running the following on the form load event;

```
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Remove(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Length - 4));

    if (pname.Length > 1)
    {
        pname[0].Kill();
    }
```

Which actually works..... once every blue moon. Seriously, it works.. the first time around, the second time the application will simply not load. If I run it about 5 more times it might run.

It doesn't seem too reliable, does anyone perhaps have a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a problem with the ordering? I'm not sure you can guarrantee that `pname[0]` isn't the new instance

Comment: Why is the new instance to be preferred over the old one? Most solutions to this problem have the new instance pass data to the old instance and then quit, which is usually an easier problem to solve.

Comment: It's a bit of an odd way for my auto-update system. But it's exactly how I want to approach it. I also believe it might be a problem with the ordering, but I assume that the first one on the list is always the oldest one. I wouldn't know how else to check it.

Comment: @Stella - Your last comment, sounds to me like you are looking for a way to restart your application as well as only allow one instance?

Comment: Okay, but even in this situation, you can probably *adapt* one of the solutions that finds the existing instance and passes data to it - instead of passing data, you pass a message that means "please abort yourself" and then the old instance can take care of actually exiting.

Comment: @Sayse, indeed. "Restarting" it probably a better description for it. Damien_The_Unbeliever, I definitely could have but I think it would've been more complicated than it should have. As it's a fairly simple application. But thank you for your input everyone. The question is answered. :)

Comment: @Stella - [`Application.Restart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart(v=vs.110).aspx) - might be of use to you..

Comment: Actually did not know about that function, thank you. But there's a chance the new instance is a newer version. So I won't be able to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me

```
if (pname.Length > 1)
{
    pname.Where(p => p.Id != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id).First().Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code instead of using executable file name to get the Process

```
Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Process[] processItems = Process.GetProcessesByName(currentProcess.ProcessName);
```

Comment: I've changed my code to this, it's definitely more elegant, but it gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your logic. Why not call Environment.Exit  when you run another instance based on condition pname. Length ==1

Comment: Then you'll have to monitor every time a process starts

Comment: No, you don't have to monitor, this code will be called whenever application is loaded, if it finds there is one already running it will close the current one which we aretrying to start.

Comment: He is trying to close the old instance not the new one

Comment: I guess the purpose is to run one instance.

Comment: It's what I'm trying to avoid, the new one has to run, the old one has to be terminated.

Comment: _I know I can apply mutex to prevent multiple instances from running_